# XQuery tag and element query

Tags: xml, database, xpath, xquery, marklogic

I have a small test of XQuery and I don't have a lot of experience with the language, one of the questions is

> Show the XQuery that will display the second paragraph (`<P>`) for the chapter with the title line “THE WORLD OF ATOMS”.

The structure of the document is `/topic/topic[1]/title[1]/ph[1]`

What I have so far is

```
for $ph in doc("chapter_09.xml")//topic
where $ph/topic/*  [ph = "THE WORLD OF ATOMS"]
return $ph
```

Comment: Please show a sample of your document. Your XPath expression by itself isn't enough to provide this information.

Answer (score 2):

```
doc("chapter_09.xml")/topic/topic[title eq "THE WORLD OF ATOMS"]/p[1]
```

Comment: You might be guessing right, but where does the "ph" element fit in? I think we need more information.